# In Boto3 how does one assign a public IP when creating an instance

Tags: boto3

I am working on an AWS VPC that has one subnet that does not auto-assign a public IP by default.  I would like to use boto3 to create the instance and automatically assign the public IP.  It's not clear how to do this from the boto3 documentation.

The closest I got was the following, but this still has errors:

`self._ec2.create_instances(
    ImageId=self._cluster._image,
    KeyName="key_pair_1",
    InstanceType="t2.micro",
    MinCount=1,
    MaxCount=1,
    SecurityGroupIds=["sg-someid"],
    SubnetId="subnet-anotherid",
    BlockDeviceMappings=[{
        "DeviceName": "/dev/sda1",
        "Ebs": {
            "VolumeType": "gp2",
            "VolumeSize": disk_size,
            "DeleteOnTermination": True
        },
    }],
    NetworkInterfaces=[{
        "DeviceIndex": 0,
        "AssociatePublicIpAddress": True
    }]
)`

Comment: What are the errors you are getting?

Comment: The issue keywords is "subnet that does not auto-assign a public IP by default" (AKA Private Subnet ).    "AssociatePublicIpAddress": True  doesn't work under private subnet.

Answer (score 9):

Might help someone:
You have to put the SecurityGroupIds, and the subnetID as a network interface parameter, and remove them from the instance parameters, then it will run fine.

```
NetworkInterfaces=[
    {
        'DeviceIndex': 0,
        'SubnetId' : 'subnet-xxxxxx',
        'Groups': [
            'sg-xxxxxx','sg-xxxx','sg-xxxxxx'
        ],
        'AssociatePublicIpAddress': True            
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

If you launch any EC2 instance inside a VPC subnet that make private (Without the Auto-assign Public IP turn on),  there is only 2 ways you can make it Internet ready
1. Attach Elastic IP after you create the instances
2. Create NAT gateway that reroute the traffic to a Subnet that allow to connect to Internet.

This instance network setup will never overwrite the VPC private subnet rules.

```
"AssociatePublicIpAddress": True
```

If the subnet features doesn't change to Auto-assign Public IP, the easiest way to do it is Elastic IP. So just add 2 extra process 
1. allocate_address  : get an Elastic IP address
2. associate_address : Attach the EIP-id to the Instance-id

Comment: You can have a public subnet that does not automatically assign a public ip address. That seems to be what the question relates to. The only difference between a public and private subnet is that a private subnet doesn't have an Internet Gateway and Routing attached. Auto-Assign Public IP does NOT define whether a subnet is public or private. The answer given below by Imre K is a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move your SubnetId within NetworkInterfaces.

It should be

    `NetworkInterfaces=[{
        "DeviceIndex": 0,
        "SubnetId": "somesubnetid",
        "AssociatePublicIpAddress": True
    }]`

And also you much make sure this subnet id has an internet gateway attached.